# HTML form values from the backend

Tags: node.js, forms

```
<form action="/users/student/update" method="POST">
    <div class="personal">
        <h3 style="padding: 0 22px;">PERSONAL DETAILS</h3>
        <hr style="width: 25%; margin-left: 0; border: 1px solid black;">
        <label for="name" class="d">Name :</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" value= profileInformation.Name name="Name">
        <hr>
        <label for="email" class="e">Email :</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" value="profileInformation.email" name="email">
        <hr>
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 2px solid black;">
    
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In this code, `profileInformation` is a data object, and name and email are variables in it. I want to use them as default values. Right now, it is being printed as `ProfileInformation.name` and not the value. Please help.

Comment: try a template engine, e.g. https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in HTML. You need javascript for that.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById("name").value = profileInformation.name;
    document.getElementById("email").value = profileInformation.email;
});
```

```js
const profileInformation = {
  name: "some name",
  email: "test@gmail.com"
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById("name").value = profileInformation.name;
    document.getElementById("email").value = profileInformation.email;
});
```

```html
<form action="/users/student/update" method="POST">
    <div class="personal">
        <h3 style="padding: 0 22px;">PERSONAL DETAILS</h3>
        <hr style="width: 25%; margin-left: 0; border: 1px solid black;">
        <label for="name" class="d">Name :</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="Name">
        <hr>
        <label for="email" class="e">Email :</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email">
        <hr>
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 2px solid black;">
    
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Okay, so I have this in a script tag. Now can you please tell me how to take it to the form?

Comment: This code `document.getElementById("name").value` will look for the DOM with id `name`, and update its value, same for the email one. You just need these codes, and your `profileInformation`, everything will work.

Comment: @shankyyyyyyy I have updated the answer with the code snippet.

Comment: I'm getting "some name" only, not the name from the object.  res.render('users/studentEditProfile',{profileInformation: profileInformation}) is my backend code

Comment: I think you need to watch more tutorials about javascript and HTML, it seems you lack the basic knowledge of javascript here...